# Expiry of RFQ order with 0x protocol

Tags: 0x

I set the expiration time of the RFQ order, but the actual expiration time of the order is inconsistent with what I set.

For example: I set up an order that is 10 seconds overdue and send it over the 0X protocol.But when I poll the order status every second through the 0X protocol, it takes 30 seconds to return that the order status is expired.

Is this normal?  What's the reason?  How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is likely due to your RPC provider being slightly delayed. If the RPC node is a block or two behind, it will think that the order is not yet expired, when in the latest block the order is in fact expired.